# Tried all means but still missing IPython

Tags: python, pip, ipython

A simple line:

```
import IPython
```

The error shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython'
```

(It looks like a duplicated question but I did searched and tried all means but the problem persits.)

I used "pip install IPython", it gives me "Successfully installed IPython-5.8.0".

```
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from IPython) (4.3.2)
```

I also used "pip install ipython"

It gives me:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (5.8.0)
```

p.s.:

1. The path "c:\python27\lib\site-packages" is included in the System Varaiblaes in the Environment Variable"
2. visual studio c++ 9.0, the version to python 2.7 is intalled

How can I have it installed? Thank you.

Comment: You are installing IPython in one python and then running a different python.

Comment: @Goyo, amazing! how can you tell I have different Python installed? I removed the Python3.7, and now the IPython works. Would you like to make it answer?